# Pentaho JMS consumer - multiple producer to a single consumer

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, pentaho, messaging

I have 2 JMS queues where my application can publish the message to any one of the queue based on the node to which the request is being received. Pentaho should actively look to both the queues and should be able to process as soon as the message arrives in any one of both the queue.

Currently, I have implemented a job to actively listen to one queue and process the message and post a response for the same.

How do we configure pentaho to actively listen to two queues at the same time and perform the same action when any of the queue is posted with a message?

**EDIT** I am not aware of any such direct feature available in Pentaho for such intra service communication.

Will Clustering help this cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally cracked it

```
Job1 
Start (Run next entries in Parallel) -> Transformation1 (JMS Consumer1)
                                    |-> Transformation2 (JMS Consumer2)
```

With the task and message prioritisation logic put on the application side.